# I want Javascript code for respective jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, css

```
   <script>
     $(function () {
        $('.headmenu li').click(function () {
           $('.headmenu li').each(function (li) {
                $(this).removeClass('selectedclass')
            });
                $(this).addClass('selectedclass');
          });

        });
    </script>
```

Please give me  alternative Javascript code for above jQuery Function.

Comment: welcome to SO. This is not a free code service, you should post your attempts and show your efforts.

Comment: [Maybe you can expend some time here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: The question might be poorly formulated but there is no need for ranting. Finding alternatives can be difficult if you don't no where to look and IMO moving on from jQuery should be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You write multiple (nested) functions here:

- Element.addEventlistener(event, callback) can be used to replace $.click().
- Array.forEach(callback, this) can be used to replace $.each() (forEach is not (yet) available for every iterable type but you can "convert/cast" iterable types).
- DOMTokenList.remove(token) can be used to replace $.removeClass() (element.classlist.remove('class').
- DOMTokenList.add(token) can be used to replace $.addClass() (element.classlist.add('class').

NOTE: When using callbacks, you might need to use function.bind(this) to make sure the correct context is passed.

Please https://developer.mozilla.org/ for more information for these methods.